Is the class of regular languages closed under the following operations?
Is the class of regular languages closed under the following operations?
(a) $A(L) = \{ w \mid \forall i ≥ 0 : w^i ∈ L \} = \{ w \mid w^* ⊆ L \}$
(b) $E(L) = \{ w \mid \exists i ≥ 2 : w^i ∈ L \}$
Can you please give a hint of how to prove it?
In (a) it seems that if $w^* \in L \therefore (ww)^* \in L$, so I can definitely rewrite it as $A(L) = \{ w^* \mid w^* \subset L \}$. So for me it seems that I can somehow eliminate some final states in finite automata of $L$, so it accepts only $w^*$. But I get stuck with further thinking about question.

Question (b) is very similar to this one asking whether the language
$$
L_0 = \{w \mid \exists n \geqslant 0 \text{ such that } w^n \in L\}
$$
is regular. More generally, the language
$$
L_k = \{w \mid \exists n \geqslant k \text{ such that } w^n \in L\}
$$
is regular for every $k \geqslant 0$. In particular, $E(L) = L_2$ is regular. For a proof, it suffices to modify my answer to the linked question by changing $Q$ to
$Q_k = \{m \in M \mid m^km^* \cap P \not= \emptyset\}$.
This proof also shows that $L_k$ is recognized by the syntactic monoid of $L$, so that if $L$ is commutative (respectively star-free), so is $L_k$.
Question (a). Denoting by $K^c$ the complement of a language $K$, note that
\begin{align}
A(L)^c &= \{ w \mid \exists n \geqslant 0 \text{ such that } w^n \notin L\} \\
&= \{ w \mid \exists n \geqslant 0 \text{ such that } w^n \in L^c\}
\end{align}
Since regular langagues are closed under complement, $L^c$ is regular. It follows that $A(L)^c$ is regular by the first part of the answer and finally $A(L)$ is regular. Since a language and its complement have the same syntactic monoid, it follows that $A(L)$ is also recognized by the syntactic monoid of $L$.
